# Rcpp: errors occurred when using template function

Tags: c++, templates, rcpp, r-bigmemory

I am revising my biglasso package to accommodate for different data types of `big.matrix`. Current version only supports `double` type. The source code is [here](https://github.com/YaohuiZeng/biglasso/tree/master/src).

What I did was to simply add the `template` header and make necessary changes to functions which take the `big.matrix` as input. The function below is an example: `xpMat` is the pointer to the `big.matrix`.

```
template<typename T>
double crossprod_bm(XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat, double *y_, int *row_idx_, double center_, 
                               double scale_, int n_row, int j) {
  // Previous code:
  // MatrixAccessor<double> xAcc(*xpMat);
  // double *xCol = xAcc[j];
  MatrixAccessor<T> xAcc(*xpMat);
  T *xCol = xAcc[j];

  double sum = 0.0;
  double sum_xy = 0.0;
  double sum_y = 0.0;
  for (int i=0; i < n_row; i++) {
    // row_idx only used by xP, not by y;
    sum_xy = sum_xy + xCol[row_idx_[i]] * y_[i];
    sum_y = sum_y + y_[i];
  }
  sum = (sum_xy - center_ * sum_y) / scale_;

  return sum;
}
```

However, after I made changes, the R package failed to compile. Below are error messages. To me it says something that is related to `crossprod_bm` went wrong:

```
Symbol not found: __Z12crossprod_bmIdEdN4Rcpp4XPtrI9BigMatrixNS0_15PreserveStorageEXadL_ZNS0_25standard_delete_finalizerIS2_EEvPT_EEEEPdPiddii
```

**Could anyone tell me what the bugs are? Are the bugs related to type conversion? I assume the type conversion in computation can be done automatically.**

Thank you very much in advance!

```
clang-omp++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/bigmemory/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/BH/include"  -fopenmp -std=c++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c gaussian_hsr.cpp -o gaussian_hsr.o
clang-omp++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/bigmemory/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/BH/include"  -fopenmp -std=c++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c gaussian_hsr_dome.cpp -o gaussian_hsr_dome.o
clang-omp++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/Rcpp/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/bigmemory/include" -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/BH/include"  -fopenmp -std=c++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c utilities.cpp -o utilities.o
clang-omp++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o biglasso.so binomial_hsr.o binomial_hsr_approx.o gaussian_edpp.o gaussian_hsr.o gaussian_hsr_dome.o utilities.o -fopenmp -lgomp -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Users/yazeng/GitHub/biglasso.Rcheck/biglasso/libs
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Users/yazeng/GitHub/biglasso.Rcheck/biglasso/libs/biglasso.so':
  dlopen(/Users/yazeng/GitHub/biglasso.Rcheck/biglasso/libs/biglasso.so, 6): Symbol not found: __Z12crossprod_bmIdEdN4Rcpp4XPtrI9BigMatrixNS0_15PreserveStorageEXadL_ZNS0_25standard_delete_finalizerIS2_EEvPT_EEEEPdPiddii
  Referenced from: /Users/yazeng/GitHub/biglasso.Rcheck/biglasso/libs/biglasso.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/yazeng/GitHub/biglasso.Rcheck/biglasso/libs/biglasso.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/yazeng/GitHub/biglasso.Rcheck/biglasso’
```

**[Update in response to @Coatless]**

I did have the dispatcher, like following.

```
template<typename T>  
List cdfit_gaussian_edpp_cpp(XPtr<BigMatrix> xMat,
                             SEXP y_, SEXP row_idx_, SEXP lambda_, 
                                    SEXP nlambda_, SEXP lam_scale_,
                                    SEXP lambda_min_, SEXP alpha_, 
                                    SEXP user_, SEXP eps_, SEXP max_iter_, 
                                    SEXP multiplier_, SEXP dfmax_, 
                                    SEXP ncore_, SEXP verbose_);

RcppExport SEXP cdfit_gaussian_edpp(SEXP X_, SEXP y_, SEXP row_idx_, SEXP lambda_, 
                                    SEXP nlambda_, SEXP lam_scale_,
                                    SEXP lambda_min_, SEXP alpha_, 
                                    SEXP user_, SEXP eps_, SEXP max_iter_, 
                                    SEXP multiplier_, SEXP dfmax_, 
                                    SEXP ncore_, SEXP verbose_) {
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xMat(X_);
  int xtype = xMat->matrix_type();

  switch(xtype)
  {
  case 2:
    return cdfit_gaussian_edpp_cpp<short>(xMat, y_, row_idx_, lambda_,nlambda_, 
                                         lam_scale_, lambda_min_,alpha_, 
                                         user_, eps_, max_iter_, multiplier_, 
                                         dfmax_, ncore_, verbose_);
  case 4:
    return cdfit_gaussian_edpp_cpp<int>(xMat, 
                                       y_, row_idx_, lambda_,nlambda_, 
                                       lam_scale_, lambda_min_,alpha_, 
                                       user_, eps_, max_iter_, multiplier_, 
                                       dfmax_, ncore_, verbose_);
  case 6:
    return cdfit_gaussian_edpp_cpp<float>(xMat,
                                         y_, row_idx_, lambda_,nlambda_, 
                                         lam_scale_, lambda_min_,alpha_, 
                                         user_, eps_, max_iter_, multiplier_, 
                                         dfmax_, ncore_, verbose_);
  case 8:
    return cdfit_gaussian_edpp_cpp<double>(xMat,
                                          y_, row_idx_, lambda_,nlambda_, 
                                          lam_scale_, lambda_min_,alpha_, 
                                          user_, eps_, max_iter_, multiplier_, 
                                          dfmax_, ncore_, verbose_);
  default:
    throw Rcpp::exception("the type defined for big.matrix is not supported!");
  }
}

template<typename T>  
List cdfit_gaussian_edpp_cpp(XPtr<BigMatrix> xMat,
                             SEXP y_, SEXP row_idx_, SEXP lambda_, 
                                    SEXP nlambda_, SEXP lam_scale_,
                                    SEXP lambda_min_, SEXP alpha_, 
                                    SEXP user_, SEXP eps_, SEXP max_iter_, 
                                    SEXP multiplier_, SEXP dfmax_, 
                                    SEXP ncore_, SEXP verbose_) {
...    
// Within this function, need call lower-level functions, e.g. crossprod_bm 
double res = crossprod_bm<T>(xMat, y, row_idx, ...)
...


}
```

**[End Update]**

**[Update 2]**

I committed all changes to [GitHub](https://github.com/YaohuiZeng/biglasso) so you can see the whole picture. I appreciate if you can give any comments.

**[Update 2]**

**[Update 3]**

I think `cdfit_gaussian_edpp_cpp` should return `Rcpp::List`. I corrected this (as above), but still got similar error.

**It seems to be that there must be something going wrong with templates in my code, maybe defining template? calling templates?**

If I don't use templates, everything works out! For example, if I revert the function captured in the error message back to not be a template function, then what happens is that function will not be captured in the error. But the next template function will be captured with similar error message.

On the other hand, however, I tried to follow [an example using `Rcpp` and `bigmemory`](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/). I changed the template function as below, which is similar to how I use template in the package. But it works!!! That makes me think I use templates correctly.

I am really confused here, and appreciate if any experts can point out the bug!! Thank you so much!

```
// Logic for BigColSums.
template <typename T>
vector<int> BigColSums2(XPtr<BigMatrix> pMat) {

  // Create the vector we'll store the column sums in.
  MatrixAccessor<T> mat(*pMat);
  vector<int> colSums(pMat->ncol());
  for (size_t i=0; i < pMat->ncol(); i++) {
    for (size_t j=0; j < pMat->ncol(); j++) {
      colSums[i] += mat[i][j];
    }
  }
  return colSums;
}

// Dispatch function for BigColSums
//
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector BigColSums(SEXP pBigMat) {
  // First we have to tell Rcpp what class to use for big.matrix objects.
  // This object stores the attributes of the big.matrix object passed to it
  // by R.
  XPtr<BigMatrix> xpMat(pBigMat);

  // To access values in the big.matrix, we need to create a MatrixAccessor
  // object of the appropriate type. Note that in every case we are still
  // returning a NumericVector: this is because big.matrix objects only store
  // numeric values in R, even if their type is set to 'char'. The types
  // simply correspond to the number of bytes used for each element.
  switch(xpMat->matrix_type()) {
  case 1:
    return Rcpp::wrap(BigColSums2<char>(xpMat));
  case 2:
    return Rcpp::wrap(BigColSums2<short>(xpMat));
  case 4:
    return Rcpp::wrap(BigColSums2<int>(xpMat));
  case 8:
    return Rcpp::wrap(BigColSums2<double>(xpMat));
  // case 1:
  //   return BigColSums<char>(xpMat);
  // case 2:
  //   return BigColSums<short>(xpMat);
  // case 4:
  //   return BigColSums<int>(xpMat);
  // case 8:
  //   return BigColSums<double>(xpMat);
  default:
    // This case should never be encountered unless the implementation of
    // big.matrix changes, but is necessary to implement shut up compiler
    // warnings.
    throw Rcpp::exception("unknown type detected for big.matrix object!");
  }
}
```

**[Update 3]**

Comment: "unable to load shared object", hm.

Comment: The next line gives some hints: ``Symbol not found: __Z12crossprod_bmIdEdN4Rcpp4XPtrI9BigMatrixNS0_15PreserveStorageEXadL_ZNS0_25standard_delete_finalizerIS2_EEvPT_EEEEPdPiddii``. We can see ``crossprod_bm`` is captured.

Comment: but not sure what the message exactly means.

Comment: The issue is the `T` is never defined in the function pass. You should also be using a model similar to: https://github.com/cran/biganalytics/blob/master/src/kmeans.cpp#L290

Comment: @Coatless. thanks for feedback. However, my understanding is that ``crossprod_bm`` can be called via ``crossprod_bm<T>(xpMat, y, row_idx, ...)``, which doesn't need to have ``T`` defined in the function pass. See https://github.com/aloysius-lim/bigrf/blob/master/src/growtree.cpp#L614 and https://github.com/aloysius-lim/bigrf/blob/master/src/growtree.cpp#L288

Comment: @AaronZeng spot on. Your function call was never defined hence the worry about an inappropriate pass (e.g. `crossprod_bm()` vs. `crossprod_bm<T>()`.

Comment: @AaronZeng: However, note that in your example they again use a dispatch method (+ macro) https://github.com/aloysius-lim/bigrf/blob/master/src/growtree.cpp#L26-L41

Comment: The dispatch in this case preserves the object type vs. using `int` associated with each `xtype` for the `SEXP`.

Comment: @Coatless, thanks, I should have been more clear. I did have dispatcher. Please see my update.

Comment: @AaronZeng, could you create a minimally reproducible example? Example should be similar to: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-bigmemory-with-rcpp/ (so the Big Sum example, except modified for the purpose of your code.)